# Run Excel VBA module for all the values of a Combo Box

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, excel-2010

I want to run a macro in Excel 2010 that uses each of the values in a combo box automatically until all the values in the combo box have been run.

For example if the combo box has the values 1,2,3,4 the code should run for each of these values passing them into a macro.

Comment: Are you wanting the macro to run against each value of the combo box automatically or only for each one when it is selected?

Comment: In addition to what @Petay87 has asked - is it the same macro you want to run for each value in the combo box or a different macro for each value?  e.g. value 1 runs Macro1, value 2 runs Macro2, value 3 runs Macro3.  Or does each value run the same macro which uses the selected value?

Comment: @Γιώργος Κοζυράκης: Welcome to StackOverflow. As it stands your question may be closed as off-topic as SO is not really the site for teaching beginners, but rather for helping to solve coding problems and bugs. Your best bet is to study the tutorials, try something out then repost your question when you need help fixing the code or making it run properly.

Answer (score 0):

From my interpretation of your question, you are looking to run certain macros (or functions) based on the selection of a value in your combo box.

I would achieve this by adding the combo box to your spreadsheet, right click on it and select "Assign Macro" give it a name and click "New".

You can then find the value of the combo box and case/switch the result:

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dd As dropdown

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set dd = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 1").OLEFormat.Object

    Select Case dd.Value
        Case 1
            Debug.Print ("Selected 1")
        Case 2
            Debug.Print ("Selected 2")
        Case 3
            DoSomething
        Case Else
            'Do Nothing?
    End Select

End Sub

Private Function DoSomething()

    Debug.Print ("Selected 3")

End Function
```